# Validate UTF-8 names with angularjs and ngPattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Is there a way to use ng-pattern in form validation to validate **any letter** from **any alphabet** (latin, chinese, korean, russian, ...).

I found a solution with the XRegExp library, but will not work with ng-pattern since it is expecting a string regex.

`XRegExp("^\\p{L}[\\p{L} ']*$")`

One solution is too build my own validator directive, but I would prefer to use ng-pattern if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `u` flag for Unicode support. That way you can specify patterns that include character categories, such as `\p{L}` for a letter in any language, `\p{M}` for an accent mark in any language.

Example:

`ng-pattern="/^[\\p{L}\\p{M}][\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Zs}'\\-]*$/u"`

Explanation:

- `[\p{L}\p{M}]` -- any letter in any alphabet, including accent mark
- `\p{Zs}` -- space separator in any language
- above pattern allows space, `'`, and `-` at the end, you can tweak the pattern if you want to avoid that

See details on Unicode and character categories at https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Comment: Isn't the `u` flag implicitly added for `ng-pattern`? It is in html.

Comment: @PoulBak: Not sure, docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern  don't mention that

Answer (score 0):

You can still use that regex in ng-pattern. You just have to pass a regex literal as a string like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^\\p{L}[\\p{L} ']*$/"
```

Comment: Code-only answers offer little help. Please elaborate in the answer so that those seeking this answer can fully understand what it is that you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-pattern="/^.{3,20}$/"
```

allow any characters (include utf-8) and limit 3-20 characters, or

```
ng-pattern="/^.[^*?&]{3,20}$/"
```

allow any characters and limit 4-20 character and except *?& (add more characters to except )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a custom directive attribute, works fine for me.
For example, below we are disallow Chinese characters for ngModel.

```
function translationModelPatternDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) {
                    return;
                }
                var regExp = XRegExp('\p{Han}');

                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return ngModel.$modelValue;
                }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (!regExp.test(newValue)) {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(newValue);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                        ngModel.$render();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
```